# Estimated mean and covariance calculation in matlab using maximum likelihood method

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am trying to calculate estimated mean and co-variance using maximum likelihood method in matlab. I am newbie in Matlab and having problems which i like to be cleared here.

I am using following code:

```
clear all;
%Visualization of 2D Gaussian Distribution
% Mean of the distribution
mu = [1 -1]; 
% Covariance matrix (Must be symetric)
sigma = [ 2 1 ; 1 3 ];

% Samples
X = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,1000);

analytical_mean = mean(X);
analytical_cov = cov(X);

N = size(X,1);

estimated_mean = sum(X)/N;
summation = 0;
for i=1:N,
 row = X(i,:);
 tmp1= (row - estimated_mean);
 tmp2 =  tmp1';
 summation = summation + tmp2;
end  

covar = summation/N;
```

Now analytical_mean and estimated_mean are coming equal but my calculated co-variance covar is not coming as a matrix like analytical_cov. Kindly I need to know how to calculate covar correctly.

I am using below equations:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
tmp2 =  tmp1'*tmp1;
```

instead of

```
tmp2 =  tmp1'
```

That change makes `covar` pretty close for me:

```
covar =

    1.9042    0.9534
    0.9534    3.0195
```

The clue was the dimensions of `covar` for you code, should have been 2-by-2 but yours was 2-by-1

Comment: Is there a typo? `tmp` doesn't exist. Only `tmp1` and `tmp2`.

Comment: I tried:

tmp2 = tmp1'*tmp1;
and I got : 4.1531 instead of a matrix.

Also as you see in the equation that there is summation sign so after summation i will still get a single value instead of a matrix.

Comment: @Umer I literally ran you code (all your code) with that change made and it returns a 2-by-2 matrix. If for some reason you have transposed `tmp1` compared with your example then yes you would get a siungle value. In that case try `tmp2 =  tmp1*tmp1'`

Comment: but I am still confused about the summation part given in the equation. Please can you explain where it is being done

Comment: @Umer What do you mean?? I didn't change the summation part of your code at all...

Comment: Ok that's fine then. As in the other answer there is not summation is being calculated so I got confused if you removed or not. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this instead

```
[m,n] = size(X);
estimated_mean = sum(X)/m;
tmp=zeros(m,n);
for i=1:n
tmp(:,i)= ((X(:,i) - estimated_mean(i)));
end
covar = (tmp.'*tmp)/m;
```

Comment: Yes I am getting the correct output now. thank for the response and help. But I am not sure where is summation been performed..

Comment: @Umer the summation in this solution is being performed here `sum(X)/m`

Comment: That is for the mean. In the co-variance equation you can see there is another summation.

Comment: You can study Matrix multiplication. The value is summed at last line, <tmp.'*tmp>.